# getElementById causing Uncaught TypeError in loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, getelementbyid

Experienced in other languages, but relatively new to HTML/JavaScript. I want the following code to work:

```
var b;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   b = document.getElementById(tools[i]).value;
   document.write(tools[i] + "<br>");
}
```

where tools is defined above as

```
var tools = [
    "barb",
    "arch",
];
```

and the Element's I'm trying to access are part of a form. However, this is giving me an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

b is set to the correct value with no errors when the code is:

```
var b;
b = document.getElementById(tools[0]).value;      // or tools[1]
```

but even this code causes an error (i.e. when the loop variable is not even used):

```
var b;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   b = document.getElementById(tools[0]).value;    // or tools[1]
   document.write(tools[i] + "<br>");
}
```

Thanks very much for any help you can give.

Comment: Can you show us HTML code.

Comment: Which element you are trying to access?

Comment: There is no problem with the code. It works perfectly fine. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/hs8apemf/ . You have to include your relevant HTML markup in the question. How do you think others will guess your use-case?

Comment: Is this code running when the page loads, or on an event? If it's the latter, that `document.write()` is going to wipe out your whole page, and `document.getElementById()` (with any ID) is indeed going to return `null` on the second iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your script is executing before the DOM elements you are trying to access are ready. Make sure to put your code in the window `onload` event (or the DOM ready event if you are using jQuery).

This will mean that you won't be able to use `document.write()` (which you shouldn't be using anyway), so you'll need an alternative (shown below):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var tools = [
    "barb",
    "arch"
  ];
  var b;
  var i;
  // specify the ID of the element where you want to insert values
  var target = document.getElementById("targetLocation");
  for (i = 0; i < tools.length; i++) {
    b = document.getElementById(tools[i]).value;
    target.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tools[i] + ' - ' + b));
    target.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
};
```

```html
<div id='targetLocation'></div>
<input id='barb' type='text' value='wire' />
<input id='arch' type='text' value='nemesis' />
```

**Edit:** One other possibility is that you have set up your code to run during some event, in which case the `document.write()` is probably wiping out your whole page. And if that is happening, then `document.getElementById()` (with any Id) will indeed return `null`.

Comment: I did set up the code to run during a specific event, on a click: `<input type="button" onclick="count()">`

So you were right. The problem was that document.write() was wiping out the whole page, so the first time through the loop it was able to access the element but the second time it had been wiped out. Thanks a lot for the help.

What is a better alternative to document.write()? Say I just wanted to put some text on the page using a variable from my script code (or any document element)?

Comment: @PJTD The example above shows a way to do that. You would need to select the location on the page where you want to insert content, and then you can add text nodes and elements to it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have a trailing comma in your array which adds an empty index at the end. Modern browsers have no issues, older ones do.

```
var tools = [
    "barb",
    "arch",  <--
];
```

Now document.write after the page is bad, it removes page content. You should be creating new elements or setting innerHTML

```
var b, i, out="";

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   b = document.getElementById(tools[i]).value;
   out += tools[i] + b + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("myOutputElementId").innerHTML = out;
```

Comment: trailing comma is allowed in es5

Answer (score 0):

That means it can't find your element named "tools" as it's looking for a tag with that id. Maybe something like this might work for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
   tools = ["barb", "arch"];
   text = "";
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < tools.length; i++) {
    text += tools[i] + "<br>";
   }

   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```